# Jersey web application registering resources dynamically

Tags: java, web-services, maven, tomcat

I have a web application, which shall load its resources dynamically from jar files.

I started to use `org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer` to setup my own server and loaded all resources via `ServiceLoader` and registered them via `ResourceConfig#register`. This worked nicely, but I had always a second server running.

Now I want to create a simple war of the application and deploy it on e.g. tomcat. The idea is, when the war is loaded, that the resources are also loaded via `ServiceLoader` and then available (so same as with the standalone server).

How must I re-write the main class that loaded and registered the resources and fired up the server, so that it is working inside a web application ?

I currently have a `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` defined, that in a method marked with `@PostConstruct` loads the resources. Though this is working, it gets initialised with every request.

I tried to add `javax.inject.Singleton` to the Application, but this resulted in the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on com.test.server.IntegrationServer
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:392)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2020)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:766)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:705)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.createApplication(ApplicationHandler.java:385)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:342)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
```

Is my approach completely wrong ? Or how can I create such a system, to be run as deployable war ?

*** EDIT ***

With using a ServletContextListener, I could solve the multiple init calls, but my resources are not loaded.

So, I have a resource like that

```
@Path("test")
```

public class TestResource implements MarkerInterface {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("get")
    public String get() {
        return "HELLO";
    }
}
This resource is packed in a jar file and is located in the file system.

The application now loads this file location and loads via `ServiceLoader` all `MarkerInterface` classes and shall register them.

I have

```
@WebListener
public class IntegrationServer extends ResourceConfig implements ServletContextListener {

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    LOGGER.info(() -> "CONTEXT INIT");
    try {
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
        // wrapper for the ServiceLoader implementation
        this.serviceLoader = new IntegrationServiceLoader();
       this.serviceLoader.loadIntegrations(MarkerInterface.class, gce -> {
            LOGGER.info(() -> "Adding " + gce.getClass() + " to Server");
            register(gce.getClass());
        });
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e, () -> "Failed to init integration server");
    }
}
```

}

I see the registration output in the log, when deploying it as `server.war` on tomcat, but when I call  `http://localhost:8080/server/test/get` I get a HTTP Status 404 - Not Found.

My web.xml looks like

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

** EDIT 2***

See Cássio Mazzochi Molin answer for this discussion.

I used the builder to register my resources and printed it out

```
Builder{names=[com.test.server.TestResource], path='backend', methodBuilders=[], childResourceBuilders=[Builder{names=[[unnamed]], path='info', methodBuilders=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethod$Builder@819f71f], childResourceBuilders=[], childResources=[], resourceMethods=[], subResourceLocator=null, handlerClasses=[], handlerInstances=[], parentResource=Builder{names=[com.cetrea.qa.server.TestResource], path='backend'}, extended=false}], childResources=[Resource{"achievements", 3 child resources, 0 resource methods, 0 sub-resource locator, 1 method handler classes, 0 method handler instances},
```

this is part of it. The TestResource has a method `info`, so I can call `http://localhost:8080/server/backend/info` and get the right result.
The resource `achievements` come from a plugin and has e.g. a `all` method, so I tried `http://localhost:8080/server/backend/achievements/all` (and also without the `backend` part), but this gives again 404

Comment: Could you merge all the questions above into a single one? Jersey looks up resource classes, by it self by default.

Comment: Not sure that I understand what you mean - I have added more information to the post. hope this makes it more clear

Answer (score 3):

Jersey offers an API for constructing resources programmatically .

According to the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/resource-builder.html), the [`Resource`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/model/Resource.html) class is the main entry point to the programmatic resource modeling API that provides ability to programmatically extend the existing JAX-RS annotated resource classes or build new resource models that may be utilized by Jersey runtime.

Have a look at the example provided by the documentation:

```java
@Path("hello")
public class HelloResource {

     @GET
     @Produces("text/plain")
     public String sayHello() {
         return "Hello!";
     }
}
```

```java
// Register the annotated resource.
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(HelloResource.class);

// Add new "hello2" resource using the annotated resource class
// and overriding the resource path.
Resource.Builder resourceBuilder =
        Resource.builder(HelloResource.class, new LinkedList<ResourceModelIssue>())
        .path("hello2");

// Add a new (virtual) sub-resource method to the "hello2" resource.
resourceBuilder.addChildResource("world").addMethod("GET")
        .produces("text/plain")
        .handledBy(new Inflector<Request, String>() {
                @Override
                public String apply(Request request) {
                    return "Hello World!";
                }
        });

// Register the new programmatic resource in the application's configuration.
resourceConfig.registerResources(resourceBuilder.build());
```

The following table illustrates the supported requests and provided responses for the application configured in the example above:

```
 Request              |  Response        |  Method invoked
----------------------+------------------+--------------------------
 GET /hello           | "Hello!"         | HelloResource.sayHello()
 GET /hello2          | "Hello!"         | HelloResource.sayHello()
 GET /hello2/world    | "Hello World!"   | Inflector.apply()
```

For additional details, check the [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/resource-builder.html).

Comment: where to put the register code into ? What structure must the class has, that  calls the `resourceConfig.registerResource` ?

Comment: @EmersonCod Could be anywhere that suits you: a `ServletContextListener`, a CDI bean, etc.

Comment: hmm - not sure I get that. So I have a "dummy" Resource (your `HelloResource`), which is only used to add the ones I load from the plugins, or what ? I tried to create an empty builder, loaded all my plugins and used `builder.addChildResource(Resource.from(gce.getClass()));`. At the end I have then `new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class).registerResources(builder.build());` to register the builder. It works when I have a class in the project and add it this way, but the resources from the jars are not available :(

Answer (score 1):

Try using ServletContextListener. That should provide you with a hook to do the same job.

Comment: thanks this does solve the multiple init calls, but my resources are not found (see edit)

Comment: Sorry, I could not figure out the error/problem you are facing with ServletContextListener. Could you please elaborate, may be with a code sample you tired ? Are you still getting the same exception?

Comment: I have added more information to the post. Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this for the last of couple of hours. With due respect solution suggested and in other question on this same problem area are half cooked. Most of the solutions do illustrate the code to scale up a REST resource programatically. What was missing for me is where do I put this code.

The correct way is given the Jersey documentation. Following is the link :

https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/resource-builder.html#d0e10860

The trick is to create your own custom `CustomResourceConfig`class which extends standard jersey `ResourceConfig` class. The CustomResourceConfig class is then passed into the the Jersey servlet as init parameter .

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>org.glassfish.jersey.examples.helloworld.MyApplication</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.examples.helloworld.MyResourceConfig</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

Please follow the jersey doc given above and I am sure things will work smoothly.

Hope this helps